# Java POI cannot find symbol WorkbookFactory

Tags: java, apache-poi

im doing a conversion of the HSSF model to XSSF.  Im getting lil errors here and there.  I donwloaded the latest POI and dropped all the jar files in and did the apache includes in my java class.....getting this error:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create();
```

275: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : variable WorkbookFactory
    [javac] location: class mil.usmc.logcom.chassis.util.HSSFUtils
    [javac]         Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no zero-arg method for [WorkbookFactory.create()](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html). For example:

```
InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
```

Comment: import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

Comment: yeah, but question....by removing the old references to HSSF..how do I instantiate a new workbook?

Comment: Just for anyone else having trouble with this. Remember that a factory method means there's NO new syntax. If you're switching from direct instantiation of XSSFWorkBook to WorkbookFactory.create() make sure you delete your "new" statement or you'll get a weird error that looks like an import issue.

Answer (score 102):

If the question you are asking is how do you find the WorkbookFactory class, that's a good question.  WorkbookFactory apparently does not reside in the poi.jar - it is in the poi-ooxml jar.

Add this dependency to your maven project and you should be able to import WorkbookFactory:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This answer must be the accepted answer as it is the exact solution to the problem described in the title. The number of upvotes also indicates the same thing.

Comment: I had to check this question twice before I found the correct answer, as I didn't think the question was relevant, because of the accepted answer. Please register this as the accepted answer, and help us all out :)

Comment: As a followup to this - another person who (thankfully) skipped the accepted answer and found the solution. I highly recommend editing the question, since it seems to be the top result for similar searches.