# Java POI Create new Workbook with SS model?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm a little confused, I used to do this:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HFFSWorkbook();
```

But with the new POI, I dont have to do that.

I can't do this:

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook();
```

I understand `WorkbookFactory.create`, but that is for opening a file.

How do I set up a new workbook with this ss model?

Comment: Q: wazakly y'all question?  How does it differ from this: [Java POI cannot find symbol WorkbookFactory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356463/java-poi-cannot-find-symbol-workbookfactory)?

Comment: How do you create a new workbook?

Comment: nope its not a duplicate..he showed me how to open a workbook with an argument....I need to create a workbook with no arguments

Comment: Dude, you create a workbook by specifying a file or an input stream :)  The file doesn't have to exist - it can be created when you save your updates.  Perhaps you mean "worksheet"? Or is there some other objection to specifying a file?  PS: Any particular reason for dropping the second "l" from "Doc Holliday"?

Comment: Well we have these methods that are called where the workbook just needs to be creted...no file is passed at the time

Comment: I dont understand your question about my username?

Comment: 1) If you have legacy code that uses the old no-arg constructor ... then I guess your options are a) update the code, or b) don't use the new API.  2) ["Doc Holliday"](http://www.legendsofamerica.com/we-docholliday.html) was a historical figure.  Spelled with two "l's", not one ;)

Answer (score 7):

You can still use the SS model but need to decide on the file format at the time of creation.

For `xls` -> `Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();`

For `xlsx` -> `Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();`

Answer (score 4):

In "New POI", you can write/read both XLS files and XLSX files. In any case, for XLS file-format you were using:

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
```

So for XLSX file-format, you have to use:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
// you could also do below
// Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
```

Also it would be helpful for you if you refer below links for starting with XLS to XLSX migration.

1. http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html 
2. http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/converting.html

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you download and add the POI JAR file to your project’s class path before running the code. The Apache POI JAR file can be found here.

```
public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

// Directory path where the xls file will be created
String destinationFilePath = "C:/Users/devesh_/Documents/HelloWorld.xls";

// Create object of FileOutputStream
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(destinationFilePath);

// Build the Excel File
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();

// Create the spreadsheet
HSSFSheet spreadSheet = workBook.createSheet("Hello_World");

// Create the first row
HSSFRow row = spreadSheet.createRow((short) 0);

// Create the cells and write to the file
HSSFCell cell;

// Write Hello
cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("Hello"));

// Write World
cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue(new HSSFRichTextString("World"));

workBook.write(outputStream);

outputStream.writeTo(fout);
outputStream.close();
fout.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating a file, you need to decide up front what format it'll be - you can't just wait until write-out time to do that. You code would be something like:

```
 Workbook wb = null;
 if (shouldBeXLS) {
    wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
 } else {
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
 }

 // work on the file in a generic way

 // save, with a suitable name
 String filename = "test.xls";
 if (!shouldBeXLS) { filename = filename + "x"; }
 FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(filename);
 wb.write(fout);
 fout.close();
```

At the start, decide what format you want for this particular instance, and create that. Treat it as a general workbook, and write to it in the common way. At the end, remember what it is so you can give the file the right extension!

(When reading a file in, `WorkbookFactory` will let you load the appropriate instance for the file type. When creating a new file, you have to pick yourself as there's nothing there yet!)